# issue in nested dictionary when try to iterate through value

Tags: python-3.x

Why below code giving me an error?

```
nested_dict = {'first':{'a':1},'second':{'b':2}}
{i for i in nested_dict.values()}
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\ABHINA~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12056/1167728052.py in <module>
----> 1 {i for i in nested_dict.values()}

C:\Users\ABHINA~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12056/1167728052.py in <setcomp>(.0)
----> 1 {i for i in nested_dict.values()}

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: nested_dict = {'first':{'a':1},'second':{'b':2}} 

{i for i in nested_dict.values()}
it is nested dictionary comprehension not the nested dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You are confused about notation.

Consider these two examples:

```
>>> {i  for i in [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]}
{('a', 1), ('b', 2)}
>>> 
>>> {k: v  for k, v in [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Using single variable `i` is asking for a `set` result.
Each element of a set must be hashable, typically immutable, like tuple, str or int.

Using the key: value notation OTOH would be asking for a `dict` result.

Answer (score 0):

Hi actually i tried this and it works:

```
nested_dict = {'first':{'a':1},'second':{'b':2}} 

for i in nested_dict:
    for j in nested_dict[i]:
        print(j)
```

and also this works too :

```
nested_dict = {'first':{'a':1},'second':{'b':2}} 

for i in nested_dict.values():
    print(i)
```